# How can do a Polymorphism with subclass in a superclass?

Tags: java, oop, polymorphism

Hello I have the following classes

```
class A <T extends AnotherClass>{
     public static A getA(){
          return new A();
     }
}
class B<T> extends A{}
class C<T> extends A{}
```

And I am trying to do a polymorphism of this way:

```
B b = A.getA();
```

But I am getting the following error:

> Incompatible types requite B found A.

How can I do work this?

Thanks

Comment: A dog and a cat are both animals, but you are trying to: Dog dog = Cat.getCat();

Comment: I am trying `Dog dog = Animal.getAnimal()` because `Dog` is `B` and `animal` is `A`

Comment: That is the only error you get? so you mean to say that public static getA() { return new A(); } compiles?

Comment: Nope, you're trying `Dog dog = Animal.getAnimal()` instead of `Dog dog = Animal.getDog()`

Comment: I just edit now, this code is only a draft for an another piece of code more big

Comment: @Tlaloc-ES are you trying to dynamically create an instance of a class, via this `static` method?

Comment: I am using a static factory to create a particular class. The real problem is that `A` is `APIResponse` `B` is another type of `APIResponse` and `C` is another type of `APIResponse`, and the `getA()` is only a method to create an `ApiResponse` with a particular API Code, because all have in common that `code`, but this is only an abstraction of these problems

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to do
`A b = new B();`
but not the other way around like you are trying to do. 
 Basically you can only put a **subclass in a super** but not a **super in a subclass**.

Answer (score 2):

**It can not work**. There is no polymorphism involved with static methods. They exist only in the context of the declaring class. So getA will always return an instance of A in your case and it will never be B.

You have not declared what type the A will be in terms of generics, but this is less important.

In this sense

```
B b = A.getA();
```

is nonsense, because `new A()` will never be `B`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't perform **Polymorphism** but you can perform **Reflection**.

You need a utility class:

```
public class ClassUtils {
public static <SUP, SUB extends SUP> void asSubclass( SUP superClass, SUB subClass ) {
for (Field field : superClass.getFields()) {
field.setAccessible(true);
field.set(subClass, field.get(superClass));
}
}
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
A a = A.getA();
B b = new B();
ClassUtils.asSubclass( a, b );
```